# Is Project Treble can be enabled by some Flags in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

I am working with AOSP 9.0(pie), but it doesn't have Treble enabled in it.
I heard somewhere that Treble can be enabled by some Flags, Is it True ?
If true, then what are the flags to be set for Enabling Treble support in AOSP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `PRODUCT_FULL_TREBLE_OVERRIDE := true` to your device.mk.

Also you need to add `BOARD_VNDK_VERSION := current` to your BoardConfig.mk

Comment: Thanks for your Response @Oleh, During Compilation i was getting some errors. I think some more changes are to be made. The error is like **LOCAL_USE_VNDK** should be defined.

Comment: such errors mean that your build is not Treble compatible enough. more info could be found here: https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk